# Powershell Cmdlet naming best practices

Tags: powershell

I have a deployment process that include obfuscation of some files before they get delivered to the client, for that, it calls into a custom C# Cmdlet currently named `Get-ObfuscateScripts`.

My question is what would be the naming best practices for such custom Commandlets, in my opinion the ideal name in this case would be `Obfuscate-Scripts`, but this gives me the warning message:

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the 'xxxxxxxx' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module com
mand again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
```

I don't really get the point of this message, if I rename it to something like let's say `Invoke-ObfuscateScripts` will intellisense work better on Powershell ISE or something like that? Or is it just saying that I should expect proficient Powershell users to be used to always explore the API by exploring the approved verbs first?

Comment: One thing is that if you used a verb not from the approved list, you will get a warning when importing a module that contains that command. So that could be annoying for users of your code. But you ***can*** use almost whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, PowerShell doesn't care what you call your functions/cmdlets, but it is good practice to follow the recommended naming standards, so users can more easily understand what your cmdlet does just from the name.  For example, it is best practice to use 'get' rather than 'query', 'lookup', 'read', etc.

The name should be in the 'verb-noun' format, using only the verbs listed here:

[Approved Verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7)

In your case, it looks like 'Protect'/'Unprotect' is the best option.

The noun part is not prescribed in the same way, but should be singular.  That is why, for example, we have `Get-Process` and not `Get-Processes`, etc.  In your case, it could simply be 'script'.

So, one possibility for your cmdlet is `Protect-Script`